# z index issue navmenu will not overlap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place some links between my top area and bottom area so that they overlap both of them by an equal amount. I have the navmenu div set to a larger z-index than all the other div's but I can't get it to overlap anything. site is at http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample1/index.html

stylesheet is at http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample1/css/styles.css

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: where is the navmenu?

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it.

You can simply specify a negative margin for your navmenu

```
#navmenu {
   margin: -10px 0;
}
```

Since you have specified the position as relative, which means the location of the `div` will depend on previous `div`. Its top would be the top plus the height of the previous `div`.

You can either change the position into `absolute`, or adjust the margin or padding values to display content inside the `div` in your way.

`z-index` will only be effective when elements are overlapping. In your case, all `div`s are in relative position. None of them is overlapping.

Comment: You probably want to read more about `position`, `float`, `margin` and `padding`. Such knowledge should help you with the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance do the following:

```
<div id="navmenu">
        <div class="inner"><h1>Test text</h1></div>
</div>
```

and than in CSS:

```
#navmenu .inner {
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin-top: -15px;
position: relative;
z-index: 200;
background-color: #F00;
}
```